# PHPUnit code coverage shows code coverage of Unit tests?

Tags: zend-framework, testing, phpunit, code-coverage, boilerplate

I'm using Michael Romer's fantastic ZF-Boilerplate and have hit a snag when testing.

When I view the code coverage reports, it only shows the code coverage for the actual unit tests, not for the code being tested.

I've looked high and low for instances of this happening, but can't find anything. As far as I can see, the phpunit.xml (https://github.com/michael-romer/zf-boilerplate/blob/master/tests/phpunit.xml) file is configured correctly for the directory structure (https://github.com/michael-romer/zf-boilerplate)

Is there anyone that can see why it's not working?

Comment: Typical... a couple minutes after I posted I figured it out. I moved the phpunit.xml up a directory, modified the paths inside it to relfect this, and tried again, and it worked as expected.

Comment: can you make your comment an answer and mark it as accepted? It helps other people because they see that your issue is solved

Comment: Sure can! I couldn't do it yesterday, as my reputation is not high enough for me to answer my own question within 8 hours of posting...

Comment: Ah, forgot about that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Typical... a couple minutes after I posted I figured it out. I moved the phpunit.xml up a directory, modified the paths inside it to relfect this, and tried again, and it worked as expected.